# Property 'styleName' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-css-modules

I tried to use react-css-modules in typescript,But I got an error message that can't add styleName to a div element.Here is the code.

```
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as  CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from 'redux';
const styles = require<any>('./style.scss');

interface RootProps {
    data: Immutable.List<string>;
    dispatch: Dispatch<any>;
}

@CSSModules(styles)
export class Root extends React.Component<RootProps, {}>{
    render() {
        return (
            <div styleName='root'>
              Hello
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root);
```

I got this error message:`'Property 'styleName' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>'`

And tsconfig

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `className`?

Comment: Instead of creating a screenshot of the code, cropping and uploading it you should have copy&pasted the code itself

Comment: I want to add a class 'root' to div element.But have to use styleName property

Comment: Why do you have to use styleName prop?  That is not a standard prop for React.  Does css-modules add that?  Usually, you would use the `className` prop to add a class.

Comment: Custom props are supported by html and therefore are useful for many things. Finding dom nodes for automated testing is a good example. I'm looking for an answer now. I'll get back when I do.

Comment: @DavinTryon The submitter in the first sentence mentioned the package he is using. If you visit their github page, they will explain styleName to you, and it's benefits.

Answer (score 9):

Use @types/react-css-modules.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-css-modules
```

Or,

```
yarn add @types/react-css-modules --dev
```

Comment: `react-css-modules` seems to be deprecated. Instead they suggest trying to use `babel-plugin-react-css-modules`. The problem is that the latter does not have typings. But, using the typings suggested in the answer worked even when using the `babel-plugin-react-css-modules`. I guess the typings adds the `styleName` property to the react-component type-definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I using VSCode IDE i just changed my Type Script version of Work Space not the IDE version.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon same error when using `preact`, add `preact.d.ts` file in your /types directory with following content:

```js
import preact from 'preact';

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface HTMLAttributes {
      styleName?: string;
    }

    interface SVGAttributes {
      styleName?: string;
    }
  }
}
```